# How to get volume/serial of a migrated vsam dataset?

Tags: mainframe, zos

I am trying to recall a migrated vsam dataset. For that , I think I need volume/serial of migrated vsam dataset. Can somebody help me how to get migrated dataset volume information ? (I think , can get it from LIST command but not getting the exact command!)

Comment: Why do you think you need the volume name? Can you show exactly what you are attemptng, and the exact text of messages which indicate that this failed, please?

Comment: HRECALL doesn't work?  How is it migrated?

Answer (score 0):

you will need special DFHSM authority but you can issue the command
HSEND FIXCDS D 'dataset name'.  It will dump some information including the volume it was migrated from.  If you have access to dcollect, you can also display information about the migrated file such as when it was migrated, the size, dcb info, etc.